# Highlight abbrev upon expansion

Tags: elisp, font-lock, abbrev

I don't really like the feeling of *not being in control* when using `emacs`' abbreviations feature. On the one hand, I don't want to be asked all the time but on the other hand I'd like to know when an abbreviation is expanded.

Hence, I fired up `emacs` (just kidding, it was already running) and did some `elisp` coding. Using some [inspiration](https://github.com/k-talo/volatile-highlights.el) I got a working prototype, that is a `minor-mode` which highlights the expansion inserted by `abbrev-mode` for some time (default is 0.5s). You can find the code below.

However, after using this code for some time, I noticed that from time to time, the seemingly random parts of the buffer are highlighted. It appears my *"hooking"* into `expand-abbrev` is not working. So here comes the actual question:

> How do you advice `expand-abbrev` such that the advised code gets only executed when there really was an expansion?

I did some digging in the `abbrev` code, added some debug statements, etc. but could not get it to work.

Furthermore, although it has been fun fiddling around with `elisp`, I don't think my code is idiomatic and I would not be surprised if there were a better way to approach the problem, thus **any comments** on the code and how it can be improved are appreciated.

Here comes the code:

```
(defadvice expand-abbrev (after expand-abbrev-after-expansion-flash)
  (ahl/add-range last-abbrev-location (+ last-abbrev-location (length (symbol-value last-abbrev)))))

(defface ahl/default-face
  '((((class color) (background light))
     (:background "yellow1"))
    (((class color) (background dark))
     (:background "SkyBlue4"))
    (t :inverse-video t))
  "Face used for abbrev highlights.")

(defvar ahl/default-time 0.5
  "Time the abbrev high light should last.")

(defun ahl/add-range (beg end &optional buf face time)
  "Add a highlight for `TIME' second to the buffer `BUF' at
the position specified by `BEG' and `END' using the face `FACE'.

When the buffer `BUF' is not specified or its value is `nil',
highlight will be added to current buffer.

When the face `FACE' is not specified or its value is `nil',
the default face `ahl/default-face' will be used as the value.

When the time `TIME' is not specified or its value is `nil',
the default value `ahl/default-time' will be used as the value."
  (let* ((face (or face 'ahl/default-face))
         (hl (ahl/--make-hl beg end buf face))
         (time (or time ahl/default-time)))
    (run-with-idle-timer time nil (lambda (hl)
                                    (ahl/--remove-hl hl)) hl)))

(defun ahl/--make-hl (beg end buf face)
  "Make a highlight at the position specified by `BEG' and `END'."
  (let (hl)
    ;; GNU Emacs
    (setq hl (make-overlay beg end buf))
    (overlay-put hl 'face face)
    (overlay-put hl 'priority 1)
    (overlay-put hl 'abbrev-high-light t)
    hl))

(defun ahl/--remove-hl (hl)
  "Clear highlight."
  (and (overlayp hl)
       (delete-overlay hl)))

(define-minor-mode abbrev-high-light-mode
  "Highlight abbreviations upon expansion." nil
  :lighter ""
  (if abbrev-high-light-mode
      (progn
        (ad-enable-advice 'expand-abbrev 'after 'expand-abbrev-after-expansion-flash)
        (ad-activate 'expand-abbrev))
    (ad-disable-advice 'expand-abbrev 'after 'expand-abbrev-after-expansion-flash)
    (ad-activate 'expand-abbrev)))

(provide 'abbrev-high-light)
```

Comment: You could use an around advice, instead of a before. And then manually check if an expansion occurred.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but the package you linked to can be extended to capture abbrev expansion like so:

```
(require 'volatile-highlights)
(volatile-highlights-mode t)
(vhl/define-extension 'abbrev 'expand-abbrev)
(vhl/install-extension 'abbrev)
```

Comment: That is interesting... had not thought of using it like that :-D My testing has shown that this will highlight from the beginning of the expanded text up to the end of line. My approach highlights only the expanded text.